# IntelliJ IDEA go-lang-idea-plugin Alpha debugging under Ubuntu

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, intellij-idea, go

I am trying to debug Go 1.4 using IntelliJ Idea 14.0.2 and the current go-lang-idea-plugin alpha 0.9.16-dev-0.9.16-alpha.9 from http://github-intellij-plugin.appspot.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/alpha.xml . As mentioned in https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/pull/588 this should work.

The plugin is working fine for running "Hello world", but my "Debug"-Button is greyed out. I already updated gdb to version 6.8.1, versions 6.8 and 6.7.7 did not work either. This is my debug configuration : 
[image: Debug config]

What am I missing? Do I need a specific gdb version or is the problem somewhere else? Or is it because I am using Go 1.4?

Comment: I wouldn't put much effort into getting `gdb` based debugging to work. It can help in very specific cases, but `gdb` doesn't provide a lot of help in highly concurrent code, especially as the flow of control passes between goroutines.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - is there a better way to debug go? I'm just starting to learn it and it's hard to find a good IDE, especially as I am kind of spoiled by Visual Studio what I used for years.

Comment: There are very few tools to debug highly concurrent code in general, and the nature of Go makes things concurrent by default. Judicious use of logging/printf is often the best tool.

Comment: @JimB Debuggers have worked great with concurrent code for a very long time. Cursive, the Clojure IDE which is also built on IntelliJ, has an incredible debugger. Needless to say, Clojure is a language that specializes in concurrent code, and receives much less developer support than Golang. This isn't an impossible problem - Go simply lags here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was :

1) Go to "Edit configuration" => "Run"

2) Uncheck "Build before run"

3) Check "Build before run"

4) Check "Enable debugging" (was greyed out before toggling "Build before run" twice).

So it was a strange UI issue.

Comment: I don't think these options exist in newer releases of this plugin.